# where can i find the codes for the machine instructions

Tags: assembly, opcode

i mean...nop is 90, push is 55 ...the others?any link?i google it but nothing came out...

Comment: You would need to identify the processor you wished to write assembler for and the your best resource is likely to be the processor handbook published by the manufacturer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this sufficient?

http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html

This is for x86, 32 bit.

Next time look for

> [your_processor] opcodes

on Google.

Comment: great!! thats what i was looking...i use objdump and i was wondering about the opcodes...thx

Answer (score 1):

[Intel has processor manuals online](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/) containing all of the published details of their x86 and x86-64 processors -- including the instruction set, how to build a system and OS around them, etc.  Volume 2 is what you want, but be sure to get both parts.  They used to actually ship paper copies of them for free (i had the PII version), but now AFAIK they just offer PDFs on the web and on CD.

Other processor manufacturers likely have similar resources.

Answer (score 0):

You must be googling something odd because there's heaps of stuff on assembly.

For example, one of my favourite references,

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly